# MySQL - Combine tables and order by max date

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables which I've simplified below. I would like to create a query which would pull the data from both tables and order by the most recent date. So if there's an entry (or entries) in the notes table it would look for the most recent notes_date for that cid, and if there's no entry it would use the contact_date for that cid.

```
contacts

+-----+--------+---------------------+
| cid | name   | contact_date        |
+-----+------------------------------+
|  1  | george | 2014-03-03 12:24:48 |
|  2  | john   | 2014-02-28 15:39:20 |
|  3  | paul   | 2014-02-14 10:13:58 |
|  4  | ringo  | 2014-02-06 07:13:17 |
+-----+--------+---------------------+

notes

+-----+-----+---------------------+
| nid | cid | notes_date          |
+-----+---------------------------+
|  1  | 1   | 2014-03-06 15:43:55 |
|  2  | 1   | 2014-03-14 20:14:12 |
|  3  | 4   | 2014-03-20 22:10:14 |
+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

This is the result I'd like to get from the query

```
4   ringo   2014-03-20 22:10:14
1   george  2014-03-14 20:14:12 
2   john    2014-02-28 15:39:20
3   paul    2014-02-14 10:13:58
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: And what have you tried. Also, for convenience, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a few parts to it.  One is getting the most recent date for notes.  Another is combining this with the `contacts` data and then choosing the right date.

The following approach uses an aggregation subquery and join to do the calculation:

```
select c.cid, c.name, coalesce(n.notes_date, c.contact_date) as thedate
from contacts c left outer join
     (select n.cid, max(notes_date) as notes_date
      from notes
      group by n.cid
     ) n
     on c.cid = n.cid
```

Comment: Gordon that's great! I didn't know about coalesce so I'm reading up on it now. I made a very slight amend to get it working for me, thanks a lot for your quick response


    SELECT c.cid, c.name, COALESCE( n.notes_date, c.contact_date ) AS thedate
    FROM contacts c LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT cid, MAX( notes_date ) AS notes_date
    FROM notes
    GROUP BY cid
    )n ON c.cid = n.cid
    ORDER BY thedate DESC

Answer (score 1):

You should use join. You can have query like-

```
select cont.cid, cont.name, nots.notes_date from contacts cont inner join notes nots on cont.cid=nots.cid order by nots.notes_date
```